# Not displaying Background image at the time of Build in React js

Tags: reactjs

Hi my app running good at localhost but when I create build then Background image not displaying.
my code is.

```
    <div  style={{ backgroundImage:"url("+require("assets/img/bg.jpg")+")", height: "400px",
                      backgroundSize: "cover",
                      backgroundPosition: "center top"}}>
```

Result at localhost as below
[image]

But at live server empty header with path
[image]

When I inspect this path then showing like this.
background-image: url(./static/media/bg6.488bc24….jpg);
Please help with thanks

Comment: Does your image available in your dist folder ?

Comment: @EmmanuelDemey yes . When I inspect and give full path then image display.
like path is this at app ./static/media/bg6.488bc249dffdae3556c6.jpg when I put  banklease folder name with  banklease/static/media........
So image display

Comment: @EmmanuelDemey my app path is https://mentorlogix.com/banklease/

Answer (score 0):

You can try importing the image outside of the function instead of requiring it.

PS:- You can kindly attach a SS of your build folder for further info.

Comment: Use comment instead of posting it as answer

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, upon build, programmatically defined path is being changed or appoints to an undesired resource.
You could try to modify your DOM and apply css, by adding a dedicated  tag, like so:

```
         <img
          id="background-image"
          src="./assets/img/bg.jpg"
          alt="background-image"
         />
```

Comment: If I display with img tag then working but not working when I want to display as background image.

Answer (score 0):

Put your file to public folder and replace require with string with path.

For example put file to public/assets/img/bg.jpg

And change path:

```
{
  backgroundImage: "url(/assets/img/bg.jpg)"
  ...
}
```

or you can use import and put imported image to img (src prop).

Comment: not working at the time of build

Comment: Sorry but it can't not work. this is 2 ways from official documentation. Files from public folders simply shared from your server. You can get it by url, find in network in source. If it doesnt work I can suppose mistake like typo or something like that. About the second option with image import, look at official docs - https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files

Comment: I am doing this but issue is this that build is not creating path like data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg...........   this path is working fine in img tag.
but in BackgroundImage build creating path like this /static/media/bg6.488bc249dffdae3556c6.jpg. So this is working in local but not in build

Comment: This is not path this is stringified image. Static path to folder its correctly.  Public folder should not be included to compile.  Problem is where you put image.

Comment: I did put image in different folders like public, src/assets/img but problem is same displaying at local server but when I deploy build then issue create with background image

Comment: You cant understand that ONLY public folder doesnt compiled during build. Just put image like I said and it will work